# How do I fix this issue when running Expo Start with Apples new Mac os software Catalina?

Tags: react-native, expo

I just downloaded the new Mac OS Catalina software and when I go to run expo using "Expo Start" in the terminal I hit an error.

I've tried using npm install or even re-installing Expo nothing seems to work.

When I'm in the terminal I run. "Expo Start" once I'm in the folder directory.

I've tried npm install, yarn install and deleting package.json

I run "Expo Start" and get the following error.

The following error is:

Cannon find module 'expo/tools/LogReporter' Require Stack: - /Users/J/Library/CloudStorage/iCould_Drive/Desktop/Coding/chadapp/noop.js

Comment: If you haven’t seen already from the github issue you linked, this has been fixed in the latest version of the expo-cli (which at the time of me writing this is 2.6.11)

Comment: How do you update expo?

Comment: `npm install -g expo-cli`

Comment: @hongdevelop Have the latest version of `expo-cli` **v2.21.2**, still getting the same error on OS X Mojave. Same error after rolling back to the suggested v2.6.11.